# How to load columns from a dataframe into the list dynamically?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

How can I load all my columns from a dataframe into the list dynamically?

Currently this is how I do it but it is very tedious:

```
list(PM = PM, site = site, code = code)
```

For instance, I have this datafame:

```
structure(list(Particles = c(0.596667, 0.27, 0.153333, 0, 0.753333, 
    0, 0.35, 0.506667, 1.6, 0.116667), PM = c(35.5158928571429, 16.0714285714286, 
    9.12696428571429, 0, 44.84125, 0, 20.8333333333333, 30.15875, 
    95.2380952380953, 6.94446428571429), timestamp = c(1493310389147, 
    1493310419191, 1493310449254, 1493310479270, 1493310509313, 1493310539387, 
    1493310569416, 1493310599465, 1493310629525, 1502378711339), 
        date = structure(c(1493310389.147, 1493310419.191, 1493310449.254, 
        1493310479.27, 1493310509.313, 1493310539.387, 1493310569.416, 
        1493310599.465, 1493310629.525, 1502378711.339), class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC-1"), site = c("ABC", "ABC", 
        "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", 
        "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC"
        ), code = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", 
        "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", 
        "ABC", "ABC", "ABC"), key_date = c("2017-04-27", 
        "2017-04-27", "2017-04-27", "2017-04-27", "2017-04-27", "2017-04-27", 
        "2017-04-27", "2017-04-27", "2017-04-27", "2017-08-10")), .Names = c("Particles", 
    "PM", "timestamp", "date", "site", "code", "key_date"), row.names = c(NA, 
    10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `as.list` or `unclass` to do this directly. Both of these return named lists.

```
as.list(dat)
```

or, you can exploit the fact that a data.frame is simply a list with a "data.frame" class,

```
unclass(dat)
```

Then, as @akrun suggests, you can subset the data.frame beforehand, or you can subset afterward. For example say a variable myVars was created through some selection process containing the names of the variables to keep.

```
myVars <- c("PM","site","code")
```

Then

```
unclass(dat[myVars])
```

or

```
unclass(dat)[myVars]
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do with `as.list` after subsetting the columns of interest

```
as.list(df[c("PM", "site", "code")])
```